# List of iphone programming websites

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-developer-program

Please put the great sites for learning objective c, essential things to iphone apps, UI codings like this with examples and codings....

Thanks....

Comment: @RajKanth: You just entered your question on best Site for this. And please don't forget to accept the answers.

Comment: That's a job for Google, not SO.

Comment: Search is a job of google... But all answers it gives, is not ideal...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267390/learning-objective-c-cocoa-for-iphone-programming-coming-from-web-development/5269834#5269834 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/how-to-articles-for-iphone-development-and-objective-c/69951#69951

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend downloading the Stanford University videos using iTunesU in iTunes.  Very informative and the course data and downloads are still available on Stanford's website.

The course page is here http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/

The videos are free in iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

**Apple's [iOS Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action) may be the most useful online all-in-one resource that you can find.**

They provide coding how-to's, getting started videos, sample code, and other such general resources, combined with all of the technical knowledge (SDKs, reference libraries, etc.) that you'll eventually need.

Answer (score 0):

In the very beginning I used resources from the Stanford University videos and then read some of the official iOS guides and references. Then I started working on an app project and tailored my learning around that. It's very difficult to learn all of iOS programming in one go without working on a project because the API is a lot to digest.

Once you've learned some of the iOS programming lingo, I would go ahead and use stackoverflow and the official developer forums to search for specific examples and solutions to the problem you are having while building your app.

Learn by doing!

Answer (score 0):

Video tutorials are a good way to learn objective C. But i would suggest that at a initial stage it can help you but when you go deeper inside into programming want to play with objective C you should opt some time to look into the Apples Documentation. [Apple's Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action) provides everything .

Dont miss thier [Sample Code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code) also.