# Learning Objective C (Cocoa) for iPhone programming coming from web development?

Tags: php, html, objective-c, css, cocoa-touch

i wanna learn to develop iPhone apps. I have a lot of experience with HTML, CSS & PHP. I also know some Javascript.
Where should i begin? I have downloaded the SDK with XCode and all that.
Am i getting ahead of myself? I have no idea really!
Any tutorials or how to's? I'd prefer not to read books :)

Thanks!

Emil

Answer (score 2):

Check out this stanford course, it is an excellent resource for learning everything you need to know:

http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2010-fall

Answer (score 2):

You have to ask yourself whether you want to learn to develop iPhone apps, or whether you just want to copy examples. Tutorials are great, but if all you do is tutorials and you never pick up a book then you'll never get the bigger picture. And the big picture is critical for an API like Cocoa. There are a lot of basic concepts (like delegates) that may be unfamiliar and confusing until you understand the underlying design patterns.

Apple's developer guides are quite good -- and maybe you can just tell youself they're not really books because they're online? :) I'd **strongly** recommend reading through them along with tutorials (or videos).

- [Cocoa Fundaments](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [iOS Technology Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with both Skue and Burt. Additionally, if you are a registered ios developer, you will have access to [developer](http://developer.apple.com/videos/iphone/) videos, which I found very useful personally, specially when I didn't want to read text books :) ios development is a vast arena of programming, so I think the best way to start learning is by start coding. 
Some things for you to start up with:
1. [iPhone](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/category/tutorials/iphone/?tag=basix) tutorials
2. [Sample](http://appsamuck.com/) [apps](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/off-topic/31642-30-days-iphone-programming-source-code.html)

Plus, for learning objective-c , I would suggest Apple's [doc](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/) on Programming to Objective-C and finally, a text book - Programming in Objective-C by Stephen Kochan.

Answer (score 0):

As a comment I'd like to recommend you to skim through [thenewboston objective-c series](http://www.thenewboston.com/?cat=38&pOpen=tutorial) and  [thenewboston iphone dev series](http://www.thenewboston.com/?cat=34&pOpen=tutorial) which actually got me started in the language and iPhone dev about 6 months ago.